# how to dynamically adding new rows to table the Date Picker fields in the new rows?

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, struts

Am working on a time sheet application with struts 1.2 and implementing jquery inside it. would appreciate greatly  if i could get reply  quickly ... am in learning curve in both jquery and struts ...

> Requirement is this :
>   On the (+) button insert a row which populates dynamically and has two timepickers in it one used for determining timefrom, the  other timeto, based on which duration is to be calculated. before clicking on (-) button user needs to check atleast one row for deleting that record.  below are the screen shots.... the timepicker plugin i used is trentrichardson's. is this possible using jtable ? or jqgrid too ?? guys advise ...

[image: requirement with timepickers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i worked it around using some of the ideas from the other users. from a newbie on struts and java perspective i found that in struts tag library id and class are given as styleId and styleClass respectively.
eg:

is written as :-

Though am still interested in knowing whether the below can be corrected further ...

http://jsfiddle.net/manmohan_menon/6YkyY/4/

any advise will be greatly appreciated... thanks! :)